# I can't open files named in Arabic in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, locale, arabic

I have an issue reading files named in Arabic. When I was on Ubuntu with Unity it could read them, but when I use KDE, they can't, unless I rename them in latin characters. I looked on some solutions I found, like Installing the Arabic language package, or this series of commands:

```
~# echo ar__AR.UTF8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local  
~# more /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local                   
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8
ar__AR.UTF8
~# sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en:ar:fr:en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_DZ.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_DZ.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales...
  ar_AE.UTF-8... done
  ar_BH.UTF-8... done
  ar_DZ.UTF-8... done
  ar_EG.UTF-8... done
  ar_IN.UTF-8... done
  ar_IQ.UTF-8... done
  ar_JO.UTF-8... done
  ar_KW.UTF-8... done
  ar_LB.UTF-8... done
  ar_LY.UTF-8... done
  ar_MA.UTF-8... done
  ar_OM.UTF-8... done
  ar_QA.UTF-8... done
  ar_SA.UTF-8... done
  ar_SD.UTF-8... LC_MONETARY: value of field `int_curr_symbol' does not correspond to a valid name in ISO 4217
LC_ADDRESS: numeric country code `736' not valid
failed
  ar_SY.UTF-8... done
  ar_TN.UTF-8... done
  ar_YE.UTF-8... done
Error: Bad entry 'ar__AR.UTF8 '
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
  fr_BE.UTF-8... done
  fr_CA.UTF-8... done
  fr_CH.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
  fr_LU.UTF-8... done
  ru_RU.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
```

How can I solve this problem? I don't want to go through my files and change their names,or go back to Unity, I like KDE.

Comment: I think you encountered an annoying Kubuntu bug. Besides posting an answer below, I just filed a [bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1395401).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid locale name set - there is no such thing as "en_DZ.UTF-8" - which makes your system fall back to the non-UTF-8 "C" locale. That's probably what's causing your problem.

I'm not using Kubuntu myself, but you should open the GUI for the language settings. Somewhere there you have probably selected Algeria as the country. To get a valid locale name, change that to e.g. United States or United Kingdom.

Next you should better remove that erroneous line in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`:

```
sudo sed -i '/ar__AR/d' /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
```

Then log out and log in again.

Finally regenerate your locale:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge
```

This time the output should be clean from error messages except for the ones about LC_MONETARY and LC_ADDRESS in ar_SD.UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as you did say, but I still can't open Arabic named files.

Comment: @Elzo: Are the Arabic characters in the file names UTF-8 encoded, or is there a chance that there is a non-UTF-8 encoding involved? Can you please list a directory with one or more such files, and paste the list here by editing your question?

Comment: Now I'm using Gnome, and the files are read just fine. The problem consists When I'm on KDE, the file names appear in Arabic on Dolphin, but when I try to open, for instance, an mp3 file with audacity, I get an error message, and the file name appears like question mark like this ????.mp3.

Comment: @Elzo: I'm out of ideas, sorry. I hoped the fix of your locale would help. Apparently not.